# Selecting Data where two columns concatenated equal something MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all of the data from my table where the people I am searching for have matching first and last names to a list of first and last names I send. The problem is First names and Last names are stored in their own columns. Is there any way of writing a query that will find all the data where those match the list of names sent.

```
myDatabase
Fname   | lname  |  email | City ...
___________________________________
John    | Smith  |jsmit...| New York...
Joe     | Smith  |jjsm... | San Fran...
Jane    | Jackson|jjack...| New Yokr...
```

I would pass a list like `'John Smith', 'Jane Jackson'` and want to return both of their rows. I know I can use `SELECT * FROM myDatabase WHERE Fname IN (...)` but I don't know how to do something like that for both first and last name when they are in separate columns.

I will try and clear up any confusion if something I said makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM myDatabase
WHERE CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) IN ('John Smith', 'Jane Smith')
```

Comment: Well, that was much easier than I anticipated. Thank you, I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to return the concatenated name you can select it and use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) as fullname
FROM myDatabase
HAVING fullname IN ('John Smith','Jane Jackson')
```